# Making a coordinate system slide around a parabola in order to ( hopefully) make a parabola slide on its fixed coordinate system.

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, rotations

The sate of my research using Desmos :https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t5w5ocxauf

My final goal is to find the equation of a parabola that is slidind on the X-axis of its coordinat system.

My idea is to reverse the question, i.e. to make a coordinate system slide on the parabola, and then to rewrite the equation of the parabola with respect to the formerly sliding system, taken as fixed.

The parabola I use if defined by $ \large f(x)= \frac 1 5 x^2$

I take the moving $Y$ axis to be the tangent to the parabola at a moving point $P= ( a, f(a))$. The equation of this tangent is :

$y = f'(a) ( x-a) + f(a) = \frac {2a} {5} (x-a)+ \frac {2 a^2} {5}$

The moving X axis should satisfy 2 conditons :

(1) it has to be normal to the tangent , that is, its slope has to be :
$ - \frac {1} { f'(a)} =  - \frac {1} { 2a/5} = - \frac {5} {2a}$

(2) it has to touch the parabola at a point $ Q= (b, f(b)$, that is ,its slope also
has to be  : $f'(b)= \frac {2b} {5}$.

It follows that $ - \frac {5} {2a} = \frac {2b} {5} \implies  b = \frac {-25} {\space 4a} \implies Q= \big(\frac {-25} {\space 4a}, f( \frac {-25} {\space 4a}\big) \big)$

Consequently, the equation of the moving $X$ axis is ( in terms of number $a$)  :

$\large y = -\frac {1} {f'(a)} ( x+ \frac {25} {\space 4a}) + f( \frac {-25} {\space 4a})$

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/t5w5ocxauf

> In which direction should I go now?
>
> Should I work on the orientation of the two lines, that is their
> inclination using the arctan function? An try to deduce the
> inclination of the moving parabola from the inclination of the alledgedly
> sliding coordinate system?
>
> Should I try to find a ( parametric ? ) equation for the movement of the two contact
> points on the movng axis, and try to translate,  after that , these
> equatons for the fixed system ? In hat case, the sliding  parabola (
> in the fixed system) will have to be tangent to the axes at these
> moving contact points?

Comment: find the origin of the moving axes ($O'$) and their rotation ($\phi$) of in terms of $a$ and you get a translation + rotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal is to slide a parabola on the axes in the first quadrant.  The parabola is defined in its own coordinate system as

$ y' = f(x') = \dfrac{1}{5} x'^2 $

And $O'x'y'$ is related to the fixed world coordinate system by

$ (x, y) = (x_0, y_0) + R (x', y') $

where $R$ is the rotation matrix

$ R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) && - \sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) && \cos(\theta) \end{bmatrix} $

Now you just need to find the location of the origin $(x_0, y_0)$ as a function of $\theta$, so that the parabola touches the $x$-axis and $y$-axis

The parametric equation of the parabola in world coordinates is

$ (x(t), y(t) ) = (x_0 + \cos(\theta) t - \frac{1}{5} \sin(\theta) t^2 , y_0 + \sin(\theta) t + \frac{1}{5} \cos(\theta) t^2 ) $

The tangent vector is the derivative of this parametric expression with respect to $t$.

$ T(t) = ( \cos(\theta) - \frac{2}{5} \sin(\theta) t , \sin(\theta) + \frac{2}{5} \cos(\theta) t ) $

If $T(t)$ is pararllel to the $x$ axis, then $T_y(t) = 0 $, from which

$ t = - \frac{5}{2} \tan(\theta) $

At this value of $t$ we want $y(t)$ to be zero as well.  Hence, we require that

$ y_0 -\frac{5}{4} \sin(\theta)\tan(\theta) = 0 $

And this gives us $ y_0 = \frac{5}{4} \sin(\theta) \tan(\theta) $

Similarly, if our parabola is to touch the $y$ axis then $T_x(t) = 0 $ for some $t$, at which

$ \cos(\theta) - \frac{2}{5} \sin(\theta) t = 0 $

From which , $ t = \frac{5}{2} \cot(\theta) $.

Now use this $t$ in the expression for $x(t)$, you get,

$ x_0 + \cos(\theta) t - \frac{1}{5} \sin(\theta) t^2 = 0 $

So that

$ x_0 = -\frac{5}{4} \cos(\theta) \cot(\theta) $

The result is [on this desmos page](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sk6oiv6oti)